# Salesforce: Get List of "Closed" Opportunity Stages

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In Apex, I need to get a list of the Opportunity stages that are closed. These are stages that, in setup, are of the type "Closed/Won" or "Closed/Lost".

I can get a list of stage names using:

`Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()`

This returns a List of `Schema.PicklistEntry` objects, but they do not indicate the type of stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you will have to query the OpportunityStage table, it has fields that flag isWon & isClosed (amongst other things) for each option.

Such a query would look like this:

```
[SELECT Id, ApiName FROM OpportunityStage WHERE IsWon = true AND IsClosed = true]
```

Comment: Gah. Thanks. I should have known that.